# how to set classpath for tomcat 6 in windows 7

Tags: tomcat, classpath

```
  please guide me how to set the classpath of tomcat in windows 7
```

i am trying to run a servlet  i also tried to set classpath for selvlet-appi.jar manually

set classpath=C:\tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar
some time it works sometimes not please help me out. I am a beginner to Servlets

when i try to compile sevlet it shows 4 errors

packege servlet does not exist

Comment: are you using any IDE ?

Answer (score 0):

Every jar you find in tomcat/lib will automatically be on the classpath of all web applications. Also, every jar in your webapp's WEB-INF/lib will be available as well as any class (in the appropriate folder) in your webapp's WEB-INF/classes.

If you don't need anything else (and this is probably the case) you will not need to configure any classpath manually.

For the compiler problems you mention: You'll need the classes/libraries in the mentioned directories on your classpath. As you don't mention what your development environment is, it's hard to say what to do. If you create a proper web application project in the IDE of your choice, everything should be there automatically

Answer (score 0):

If you want set classpath set manually
goto tomcat folder where you installed and lib->servlet-api.jar
Copy path and paste to environment variable java path continue and end with;